# Inline-block how to wrap to top line

Tags: css

I have 4 inline blocks in a 100%w container.When i resize de browser to overflow this container add browser adds new line on the bottom but i want the new line to the top, is there anyway of doing it?

```
**Full browser width:**
*** *** *** ***
*1* *2* *3* *4*
*** *** *** ***

**Overflow**

Doing this:

*** *** ***
*1* *2* *3* 
*** *** *** 

***
*4*
***

I want this:
***
*4*
***

*** *** ***
*1* *2* *3* 
*** *** ***
```

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="cajonera">
        <nav class="contenedorWidgets">
            <ul>
                <li>image1</li><li>image2</li><li>image3</li><li>image4</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .cajonera{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #040404;
    position: absolute;
}
.contenedorWidgets{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:63px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;

}

.contenedorWidgets ul{
padding: 0;
margin:0;
list-style-type: none;
list-style: none;

}

.contenedorWidgets ul>li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: -4px;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What you want is that 4th image should move at top if it overflows. You can't do this with pure CSS. You need to use JavScript for this

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do that with [Flexible Box Layout Module](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and **`flex-direction: column-reverse`** but for now it doesn't work in all browsers...or it may, spec did change too many times in the past 2 or 3 years ^^

Obviously doesn't work in IE8- and to be tested in IE9, IE10, Opera, Firefox 21/22... **[Demo for WebKit](http://www.alsacreations.com/xmedia/tuto/exemples/flexbox/flextest03b.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm hardly touting this as a good solution, it's pretty "hacky" but here you go:

```
<div class="container">
        <nav class="widgets">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
                        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li><li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

And the CSS (I use a media query to push the 4th `<li>` item up on top):

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: absolute;
}
.widgets{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:63px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;

}
.widgets ul{
padding: 0;
margin:0;
list-style-type: none;
list-style: none;

}

.widgets ul>li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
 }
@media (max-width: 400px) {
.widgets ul li:nth-child(4n) {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-70px;
}
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/MBxxt/2/

Answer (score 0):

You may use float and clear effects.
Selectors will help you to float or not elements and wich should clear to draw new line.

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/aCDhm

For a list or 4 items, this CSS rules will do it.

```
ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:2em;
  list-style-type:none;
  border:dotted;
  display:inline-block;
}
ul:before {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  height:50px;
  margin:4px 0;
}
li {
  margin:3px;
}
li:first-child {
  clear:left;
}
li:not(:last-child) {
  float:left;
}
```

When to apply this rules ?

Use mediaquery and screen width whenever you want line to break and where.

See this demo as a clue how to write you rules.
Decide your self  wich stays on top, wich breaks line and wich follows according to screen width.

You could keep 2 on top not floatting ,and have 2 others staking , drawing 3 lines. (lego games)